# Positioning key:value of an object

Tags: javascript

is there any way of moving **key:value** pair from one position  to another inside an object? I knew this on arrays and I Googled , in vain, an easy way to do it.

I renamed a key from "id" to "mentorId" and it took the last position yet I want to be on the first position.

**The code for renaming**

```
 value['mentorId'] = value['id'];
 delete value['id'];
```

**My response body**

```
{
    "status": 200,
    "message": "All Mentors",
    "data": [
        {
            "first_name": "Brick",
            "last_name": "Ken",
            "email": "brick@gmail.com",
            "address": "kigali",
            "bio": "so successful",
            "occupation": "army",
            "expertise": "3 years",
            "is_admin": false,
            "is_mentor": true,
            "mentorId": 2
        }
    ]
}
```

Everything else is fine except this index issue. I would appreciate your help. Thanks.

**PROBLEM SOLVED**

I recently asked this question and thanks to the help of you all good devs  I used your input,  searched the internet and finally found the solution. Here is how I implemented what I wanted in this **allMentors** static method:

```
static async allMentors(req, res) {

        try {

        users.forEach(user => {
            if(user.is_mentor === true) {
                mentors.push(user);
            }
        })

        const ObjKeyRename = (src, map) => {
                const dst = {};

                for (const key in src) {
                    if (key in map)
                        // rename key
                        dst[map[key]] = src[key];
                    else
                        // same key
                        dst[key] = src[key];
                }
                return dst;
        };

        const uniqueMentors = Array.from(new Set(mentors.map(m => m.id)))
                .map(id => {
                   return  new Promise((resolve, reject)=> {
                        const currMentor =  mentors.find(m => m.id === id);
                        const modMentor =  ObjKeyRename(currMentor, { "id": "mentorId" });
                        return resolve(modMentor);
                    })
                }) 

        Promise.all(uniqueMentors).then(output => {
            output.forEach(async obj => {
               await delete obj['password'];
            })

            return res
            .status(200)
            .json(new ResponseHandler(200, 'All Mentors', output, null).result());
        })
```

Comment: you have an array with one object.  Is that what you intended, or where each key:value pair is an element?

Comment: That said, it's generally best to not rely on property order in the first place, and make your code that depends on it more flexible instead.

Comment: @OldProgrammer, I intend to have many objects inside the **mentors** array with an incremental **mentorId**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Object properties can't always be depended on to be ordered. Sometimes they can be, but often they aren't (such as with JSON serialization/deserialization, `Object.keys`, and `for..in` loops).

If you're using a method that in ES6+ *does* have a guaranteed order for iterating over keys (like `Reflect.ownKeys`, object rest/spread, `Object.assign`, `Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptors`, `Object.getOwnPropertyNames`, and so on - look up uses of [OwnPropertyKeys](https://tc39.es/ecma262/)), then the other keys will have to be added after the `mentorId` key has been added. While this could be done with mutation via some messy `delete`s, creating an entirely new object for that place in the array would probably be a lot cleaner:

```js
const body = {
    "status": 200,
    "message": "All Mentors",
    "data": [
        {
            "first_name": "Brick",
            "last_name": "Ken",
            "email": "brick@gmail.com",
            "address": "kigali",
            "bio": "so successful",
            "occupation": "army",
            "expertise": "3 years",
            "is_admin": false,
            "is_mentor": true,
            "mentorId": 2
        }
    ]
};

const { id, ...rest } = body.data[0];
body.data[0] = {
  mentorId: id,
  ...rest
};
console.log(body.data);
```

Comment: I upvoted the answer but I still have less than 15 reputation because I've just started interacting with the dev community here and  you know my upvote  won't change the votes publicly.